# Stuck in windows start up failure loop, any hope or do I need a new HDD?

Tags: windows-7, crash, boot

Every time I boot my laptop (HP Envy 14) it goes to a start up failure screen and I have the option of starting windows in repair mode (recommended) or starting windows normally. either option freezes the computer at the windows is starting up screen, at a light blue screen that looks like the windows login background, brings me back to the start up failure screen, or, if i disable auto restart on start up failure, brings me to some type of blue screen of death.

I spoke to HP support and they told me to try and do a self hard disk test in BIOS. The test completed the first half but froze on the second. They then asked for the hard disk information in the main tab in BIOS but it is no where to be found. The Rep then told me to press f11 to do a system recovery but that brought me to another frozen screen. (attempting to boot into safe mode also brings me to a freeze screen). The rep then wanted me to get it sent in for HDD repair. This laptop is less than 2 months old! I see a lot of people with this problem doing a google search but all of the solutions involve booting from a clean install of windows disk (dont have) or booting into one of the modes that bring me into a freeze screen. I only have the recovery disks I made when I first got the laptop.

So, What do you guys think, is there anything else I can try or should I just get it warrantied. (2 months after purchase -_-)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the HDD brand, try downloading the manufacturers test utility and see what that tells you. If the drive really is good, then do a recovery from your recovery disks, and see if you can get HP to send you a real oem Windows dvd. Otherwise, send it in if it's bad, because it won't get better.

Comment: Download the manufacturers test utility on my other machine or on the machine with the problem? < (not possible)

Comment: They test utilities are usually small tools that you'll need to boot from a usb stick or cd. Another option is to try Ultimate Boot CD, which is supposed to contain utilities from several manufacturers...http://www.ultimatebootcd.com. The utiliites will sometimes check your drive's firmware, letting you know if it needs updating. This could be the case here.